# Make Smartglass connection last longer with Xbox

Tags: networking, windows-8, xbox360

I quite often use Smartglass from both my phone and tablet to control my Xbox, typically as a remote control for things like Netflix. It works well, the one downside is the constant reconnecting process - usually 10-15 seconds. The usual scenario is someone/something will interrupt the show so I'll want to pause.

Even if the app is still running in the background of the device, I'll switch back to it but still have to wait for it to connect. It seems only if I switch back to the app within about the first 1-2 minutes after it was active will I be able to resume exactly where I was without it having to reconnect.

So the question: is there something I can do to prevent the connection loss happening so quickly / at all? Probably at the expense of some battery life but I'd almost rather that.

Comment: Are we talking about Android, Windows, or Apple device?  Is your device going to sleep and if so have you increase the time before that happens to see if that helps?

Comment: Apologies, using a Windows Phone (7.8 or whatever the number is now) and a Surface 2. It doesn't make a difference if the device sleeps or not, only if the Smartglass app is active on the screen. I can be using my tablet to do other things - never going into sleep - then go to use Smartglass and have to wait.